# python and django: execute python script from django web form?

Tags: python, django

I have fully functional python program which I run from shell. All arguments and options are supplied using option parser. What I would like to do is to create simple web interface for this program using django.

I am stacked on transferring values received from web form to python script ))
Actually how can I execute python script in this way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your python program has a bit that looks like this:

```
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
  args = sys.argv 
  main(args)
```

Then just import it, and call it's main() method with your args in the same format as sys.argv. Sorted. That would be the pythonic way of doing things.

Otherwise you need a general way of executing an external program from python - os.system and its friends. This is covered elsewhere.

Comment: The task was to write simple web interface for script without any changes to this script. So I had to construct string with args and opts, eg scr.py -h host.com -p 22.... I managed to do this in following way. in my viwes.py function that processes data received from form writes values to a list, eg ['-h host.com','-p 22']. Then I call my script runner = SubprocessThread('python scr.py %s' % (holder.args_and_opts)), where args_and_opts = " ".join(list).

Comment: You should almost **NEVER** supply command line parameters like that, especially if the interface is available from the Internet. The Python `subprocess` module provides you several methods to provide the parameters in a list, which is more secure and performes better because there's no shell involved by default.